# Finding the value of the next iteration of an array pointer in C

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, pointers

Normally, when trying to reference the value of a pointer, one would use `&p` for the pointer `p`, so if I have a for loop that iterates through `p`, a pointer that points to an array, and I want to compare the value of `p` to that of `p+1` I've ran into a bit of an issue. When I type

```
if(&p < &(p+1){
   foo();
}
```

and in response, I get this error:

```
error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand
```

It's worth noting I'm using C89 and the assignment I'm doing doesn't allow me to access the array values directly with `arr[value]`, it's unfortunately required for what I'm writing this for. How do I go about accessing the value of `p+1`?

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to achieve? This looks a bit like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Anyway the value of your `p` pointer here is simply `p`. `&p` is the memory address where the pointer is stored.

Comment: If `p` is a pointer then `&p` is a pointer to the pointer variable itself, which seems wrong. What are you really trying to do? What is the actual problem you try to solve using pointer to pointer?

Comment: It's a bubble sorting algorithm, but i'm not able to access values in the array directly with ```array[value]```

Comment: You do know that for any array *or pointer* `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is exactly equal to `*(p + i)`?

Comment: _"i'm not able to access values in the array directly with `array[value]`"_: huh?  Why not? Does it not compile? Does it not give the result you expect? I think you should [edit] your question and show some context.

Comment: The question seems to come from a basic misunderstanding of the C language basic concepts. Could you, please, describe the main problem (_what_ you're trying to achieve) and show your attempt, that is a complete piece of code (_how_ you're trying to to achieve the goal). That would make a context for solving the issue, which is lacking in the presented single `if()` with a semantically invalid condition expression.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It's part of the assignment guidelines, sorry, I should have clarified this originally.

Answer (score 4):

The `&` operator returns the address of its operand. You want the value, which is the `*` operator for dereferencing.

```
if (*p < *(p+1)) {
    foo();
}
```

Of course, you have to ensure that you don't do this when `p` points to the last element of the array, since `p+1` points outside the array.

Comment: The unary `&` operator returns a _pointer_ to its operand which is not precisely the same as its _address_.

Comment: From the C standard: **The unary & operator yields the address of its operand.** http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p3

Comment: ...and **the result has type ''pointer to type''**, which is not just an address, but also an implicitly associated size of the pointed object, used in pointer arithmetics.

Comment: So what? If I said that `pow()` returns a number, would you correct me and say that it returns a double?

Comment: So nothing. For you. And for me. But for OP, who has problems with "which operator to use, `&` or `*`" it may be rather important to internalize the difference between a pointer type and a raw address.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the *p instead &p if you are going to reference the value of pointer 'p'. The '&' operand is the address of 'p', not a value.
So, you must do like this:

```
if (*p < *(p + 1)){
    foo();
}
```

I suggest one sample below

```
void foo()
{
    printf("foo\n");
}

int main() 
{
    int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} ;
    int * p = arr;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (*p < *(p + 1))
        {
            foo();
        }
        p++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```